# Publishing a database project with Always On Encryption and Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-keyvault, database-project, sqlpackage

I have an existing SQLAzure database. We are developing a new feature and need to have column level encryption. I am researching how to set this up.

We currently push changes to our local and to production via a database project. A simple right click > publish.

When I do this in my local environment after setting up the column encryption with the key stored in the Azure Key Vault, I receive the following error.

> Cannot proceed as Key Vault support is not present in the current
>   application. For Key Vault support during deployment, install
>   DacFramework.msi and run SqlPackage.exe from its install location.

I've done that and still receive the same error.

Is it possible to maintain the right click publish functionality with the column level encryption or will I need to create an external script to set this up from now on?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the newly updated hosted agent has a newer version of the DAC framework installed which is taking precedence over the full version that was installed separately, or else there is some other sort of discrepancy between the two and your system is trying to use the older version of the framework. It is also possible that some of your VMs have the framework and others do not, and this is causing that error.

There is a [known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/8194) with that error message that the product team is working on. See also, the [user voice item](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32908189-dacpac-deployment-problem-when-files-are-moved-fro).

Can you provide any of your error logs for further troubleshooting?

I would also recommend sending an email with your subscription ID to AzCommunity@microsoft.com so that I can open a support case for you. It will be easier to diagnose with more insight into your environment.